# Doctrine ORM 2 Select On Negative Numbers

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine Orm in a Silex project I'm currently working on. My problem is that my accounts transaction entity sometimes has negative Doubles in the "amount" field. This is fine, the entity saves. The problem is when using findOneBy the select query turns the float value into a string and thus it does not find it.

My Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AccTrans
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acc_trans", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_acc_trans_acc1_idx", columns={"acc_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AccTrans
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="acc_trans_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $accTransId;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="float", precision=12, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="validated", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $validated = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \Domain\Entity\Acc
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Domain\Entity\Acc")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acc_id", referencedColumnName="acc_id")
     * })
     */
    private $acc;



    /**
     * Get accTransId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAccTransId()
    {
        return $this->accTransId;
    }

    /**
     * Set amount
     *
     * @param float $amount
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    /**
     * Set validated
     *
     * @param integer $validated
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setValidated($validated)
    {
        $this->validated = $validated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get validated
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getValidated()
    {
        return $this->validated;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set acc
     *
     * @param \Domain\Entity\Acc $acc
     *
     * @return AccTrans
     */
    public function setAcc(\Domain\Entity\Acc $acc = null)
    {
        $this->acc = $acc;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get acc
     *
     * @return \Domain\Entity\Acc
     */
    public function getAcc()
    {
        return $this->acc;
    }
}
```

My Entity save code:

```
$entity = new \Domain\Entity\AccTrans();

$entity->setAcc($acc_entity);
$entity->setAmount(-(number_format($amount, 6)));
$entity->setValidated(0);
$entity->setDescription("Data Purchase");

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

The query generated by Doctrine (From the Doctrine Logs):

```
INSERT INTO acc_trans (amount, validated, description, created_at, updated_at, acc_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"params":{"1":"-0.300000","2":1,"3":"Data Purchase","4":null,"5":null,"6":394},"types":{"1":"float","2":"smallint","3":"text","4":"datetime","5":"datetime","6":"integer"}} []
```

Now, when I call findOneBy using exactly the same data, the query generated by Doctrine is:

```
SELECT t0.acc_trans_id AS acc_trans_id_1, t0.amount AS amount_2, t0.validated AS validated_3, t0.description AS description_4, t0.created_at AS created_at_5, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_6, t0.acc_id AS acc_id_7 FROM acc_trans t0 WHERE t0.acc_id = ? AND t0.amount = ? AND t0.validated = ? AND t0.description = ? LIMIT 1 {"params":[394,"-0.300000",1,"Data Purchase"],"types":["integer","float","smallint","text"]} []
```

As you can see the second Parameter is now converted to a string ("-0.300000" instead of -0.300000) and the result is not found. What am I missing here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - the trick was using Decimal data types instead of Float. Hope this helps someone in future.